# Unable to Save List item after using PreSaveAction() function in NewForm.aspx page

Tags: javascript, ootb

as per my requirements

- Check current user is present in **manager** group
- If not present Check status columns
- If status column consist value other than **Requested**  then stop user to **Save** item

so for that I have used **PreSaveAction() function.**
I have achieved my requirement here but not It stop save item in list even if Member is available in **manager** group

Here is screen shot of List Item 
[image]

Here is my code

```
 var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = context.get_web();

    var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);

    var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    context.load(allGroups);

    var group = allGroups.getByName('Marketing');
    context.load(group);

    var groupUsers = group.get_users();
    context.load(groupUsers);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
            function(sender, args) {
               var userInGroup = IsUserInGroup(currentUser,group);   

            if(userInGroup)
               {
                alert('avaliable in group');
                return true; 

               }
             else
               {
                var txtTitle = j(":input[title='Status']").val(); 

                if(txtTitle != 'Requested')
                { 
                  alert("Please Select other status ");
                  return false; 
                 }
                else
                { 
                 return true; 

                }

               alert('Not avaliable in group');

               }

            },
            function OnFailure(sender, args) {
               alert('Not Avaliable');
                var userInGroup = IsUserInGroup(currentUser,group);   
               alert("Not");
            });


    function IsUserInGroup(user,group)
    {
        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        var userInGroup = false;
        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == user.get_id()) {
                userInGroup = true;

                break;

            }
        }
        return userInGroup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because you are doing it async, instead of returning `return true`, send in the form using `SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm`

Its already available on the `form` variable created by SP:

```
window.form.SubmitClientForm()
```

If you are using `PreSaveAction`, you'll need to return false on the initial save to avoid multiple "saves":

Example:

```
window.PreSaveAction = function() { 
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() { 

        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        context.load(context.get_web(), "Title");
        context.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
                form.SubmitClientForm();

        }, function(s,args) { console.log(args.get_message()) })

    });


    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Anders Aune Your solution works for me..
But it save item 2 times.. 
don't know but I will Figure it out.

Comment: Same issue for me item save 2 times how can you avoid ?

Comment: @Admin updated my answer